# How can I properly reference environment variables in CircleCI

Tags: circleci

If I use a environment variable the circle.yml bellow, fails, But if I statically type the machine name it will work.

How can I properly reference environment variables in CircleCI?

```
version: 2
executorType: machine
stages:
  build:
    workDir: ~/app
    enviroment:
      - IMAGE_NAME: "nginx-ks8-circleci-hello-world"
    #   - AWS_REGISTER: "096957576271.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    steps:
      - type: checkout
      - type: shell
        name: Build the Docker image
        shell: /bin/bash
        command: |
          docker build --rm=false -t $IMAGE_NAME .
```

Answer (score 0):

I check your syntax with this example of circleci docs https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-python/#config-walkthrough so you have to remove the hiphen

```
enviroment:
  IMAGE_NAME: "nginx-ks8-circleci-hello-world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats for the environment variable inside the docker image for CircleCi 2.0.

Circle runs each command in a subshell so there isn't a way to set environment variables for the CircleCi build from the build itself.

Instead use the actual CircleCi environment variables:
https://circleci.com/gh/{yourOrganization}/{yourRepo}/edit#env-vars